# Python Discord Read Attached Filename

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm trying to make a for fun discord bot that responds to my friends when they post a screenshot from a video game we all play but it doesn't seem to be working correctly

all screenshots would be named something like

> 'Hearthstone_Screenshot_11-02-21_22.46.47.png'

and I thought this block of code would work inside my event handler but it isn't detecting the screenshot when i test it

```py
if message.attachments:
    for m in message.attachments:
        if m.filename.startswith("Hearthstone_Screenshot"):
            await message.channel.send(f"Did you win? {messsage.author.mention}")
```

Comment: Perhaps try debugging first with a `print(m.filename)` before the if startswith statement.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe it uses `/full/path/to/image.png` - always first use `print()` to see what you really have in variables.